# the_post_thumbnail( array(x,y) );

Tags: wordpress, resize

I am trying to use the WP function the_post_thumbnail( array(x,y) ); but the images are are failing to resize properly. It's just not working correctly.

Specifically in the page-template.php file I'm building I am trying to use:

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(200,200) );
```

Yet the resulting image is 200 x 150. What am I missing here?

I tried to explicitly add the thumbnail size to functions.php like so:

```
add_image_size( 'news-feature-thumb', 200, 200, true );
```

But it made no difference.

I looked all over StackOverflow, but I've seen nothing that answers my problem. I am using WP 3.3.1. Is this method deprecated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you added `add_image_size( 'news-feature-thumb', 200, 200, true );` try calling `the_post_thumbnail` like that:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'news-feature-thumb' );
```

Comment: It worked! So am I correct in thinking the array(x,y) parameter is deprecated? (Or at least not up to spec?)

Comment: Not sure why array(x,y) doesn't work, reading the specs it should. But I had quite a few cases with WordPress, where something should have worked but didn't so I was forced to discover a workaround. Anyway I'm glad this one worked. Please take a moment and accept the answer by clicking on the big checkbox in the left side of this answer. You even get some points doing that :)